# Calling json data in an existing i tag field

Tags: json, reactjs, forms, calling-convention

```js
[
    { "id": "1",
        "First Name": "John"
    }
]
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Mcontent.css';
import editProfiledata from './edit-profile-data.json';

class Mcontent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(

       <body>

        <div className="box1">

          <form method='post' id='editprofile' action=''>

              <h1> Edit Profile </h1> <br/><br/>


              <div className="name1">
                <label for='Fname'>Name:</label><br/>

                {editProfiledata.map(profileinfo => (
                    <input type='text' name='Firstname' id='Fname1'                         
                      maxLength={10} placeholder='First name'                               
                      required key={profileinfo.id} value=                                  
                      {profileinfo.FirstName} />
                ))}
                 <br/><br/>
```

[Input field for first name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkFih.png)

I am creating an edit profile form for my website and I would like to be able to call data from a json file in order to test my form. I've tried using the code above but it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have [**json-loader**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader) installed :), then you can use

```
import editProfiledata from './edit-profile-data.json';
```

or

```
import editProfiledata from './edit-profile-data';
```

You can install it with

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

Comment: I added the package but it didn't seem to make a difference because the resulting page is showing me the field as opposed to the data in the json file